# Cannot test mongo aggregation MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs, aggregation-framework

Im using mongo aggregation with mongoose. It works fine, but fails when run in jest.

I get the error:

```
MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'
```

when using $set inside an aggregation

```
$set: {
            isUsersContent: {
              $eq: ["$teacher._id", user._id],
            },
      }
```

"mongoose": "^5.3.12",
"jest": "^25.1.0",

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `$set` MongoDB Aggregation pipeline stage will work only for MongoDB versions 4.2 and above.

You can use the `$addFields` Pipeline stage instead.

```
$addFields: {
            isUsersContent: {
              $eq: ["$teacher._id", user._id],
            },
      }
```

> Note: The `$set` Aggregation Pipeline stage is nothing but an alias `$addFields` stage

Comment: Awesome, thanks ! I thought mongoose would use the latest stable version by default.