# MongoDB - combining query across mulitple collections

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to figure out how to essentially do a join in MongoDB. I've read about doing aggregates: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

I'm also very new to NoSQL, so I'm not exactly sure what I should be using here.

I have two collections in MongoDB, structured as follows:

**db collection - employees:**

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: 'John Doe',
  filesAccess: {
     web: true
  },
  fileIds: [
     'fileId1',
     'fileId2'
  ]
},
{
  _id: 2,
  name: 'Bob Jones',
  filesAccess: {
     web: false
  },
  fileIds: [
     'fileId3',
     'fileId4'
  ]
}
```

**db collection - files:**

```
{
   _id: fileId1,
   fileMetaData: {
      location: 'NE'
   }
},
{
   _id: fileId2,
   fileMetaData: {
      location: 'NE'
   }
},
{
   _id: fileId3,
   fileMetaData: {
      location: 'SW'
   }
},
{
   _id: fileId4,
   fileMetaData: {
      location: 'SW'
   }
}
```

I want to be able to query for all employees who have `fileAccess.web = true` and get their employee ID, name, and `fileMetaData.location`. The `location` for all of an employee's files will be the same. So the query only needs to use the first `fileId` from an employee to get the `location` from the `files` collection

So I'd like my result should look like:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   name: 'John Doe',
   location: 'NE'
}
```

How would you structure a query to accomplish this in MongoDB? I'm using Studio3T as my interface to the db. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First `$match` to get only documents where `filesAccess.web` is true.
- The join based on values on `fileIds` and `_id`. This give an array calling `result`.
- Then get the first position
- And `$project` to output the fields you want.

```
db.employess.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "filesAccess.web": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "files",
      "localField": "fileIds",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "result": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$result",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "location": "$result.fileMetaData.location"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1y1LLAEt1oN)

Comment: This is great, thank you! Looking at the example you linked, this seems to be what I'm looking for. I tried to put this query into Studio3T and got the error 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set''. Do you know if there's something I need to change to get this to execute in Studio3T?

Comment: Which version of mongo are you using? [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) is new in 4.2, maybe you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)

Comment: Ah yep, that's it! I just found it by reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624944/cannot-test-mongo-aggregation-mongoerror-unrecognized-pipeline-stage-name-se. I'm on 4.0.15 so that was it. Thanks so much, I learned a lot from this!